# Addition in a prime based notation system

Tags: notation, prime-numbers

I have been experimenting with using a prime based notation system. The system assigns place value based on powers of the prime numbers multiplied together instead of multiples added. Examples:

```
11   =   6 (3^1 * 2^1)
221  = 450 (5^2 * 3^2 * 2^1)
1001 =  14 (7^1 * 5^0 * 3^0 * 2^1)
```

This make multiplication very easy - just add the digits, but I am confusing myself a little on addition.

Does anyone have any thoughts on whether addition in using this notation is even possible? Do I need to convert to a traditional multiples added together system before adding?

Comment: This does make it difficult to add, as you note, but easy to multiply.  Also there is no guarantee that prime powers will be "single digits", so it doesn't do away with a need for something like positional notation.  For example, how would you write one thousand twenty-four with your system?  See [Gödel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering).

Comment: Note that you will need a separate symbol for each natural number, as the usual decimal multiplication $32\cdot32$ becomes $5\cdot 5=10$, except it's not three. Also, note that the $abc$ theorem, that was only recently proven, regards the structure of addition in this system (specifically, which positions will be non-zero), and it was not an easy theorem to prove (it implies Fermat's last theorem, and until Wiles' proof it was believed that Fermat's would be proven this way).

Comment: Yes, separate symbols for each natural number was my first task. I have developed a system for generating about 100 easily distinguishable symbols. It continues beyond that to infinity but they get harder to tell apart as they get larger. I think that is acceptable though since 1000000 and 10000000 are also hard to differentiate, and because any digit to the power of 40 is large enough that I would be using abbreviation at that point anyway.